# Solar system like interactive 3d animation in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, core-animation, ios-animations

I need to implement a solar system like 3d interactive menu animation for my application, where i can scroll through through sub items and should able to select the items, I don't know how to achieve this in both android and ios any libraries are available to achieve this?

[image: when user clicks centre,its starts the animation]

[image: after 30 sec of animation frame look like this]

Comment: Check out unity3d - pretty easy there.

Comment: You can try unity3d as @Skynet pointed it out. You can also use Cocos2D or SpriteKit for iOS. Its a great framework and meant for the use of Sprites.